# How to add a drained node back again in kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, devops

We had a situation where we had to drain a Kubernetes node.
[image: K8S drained node]

Is there anything I can do to enable pod scheduling back again? Please suggest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've most likely used the `kubectl cordon <node name>` to set your node as un-scheduleable.

To revert this you can run `kubectl uncordon <node name>` to make it schedulable again.

If this doesn't allow you to schedule on this node please provide the outputs of `kubectl describe node <node name>`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @yomateo. kubectl uncordon <node name> worked for me.

Comment: I accidentally used `kubectl drain node xyz` , and then use `kubectl delete node xyz`. Then, I want to joint this node again, but getting the error like `error execution phase preflight: coundn't validate the identity of the API server: abort connecting to API servers after timeout of 5m0s`.   Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: For me uncordon does not work. After 1 minute, it returns back to Ready,SchedulingDisabled. What should I check ?